# How to prove/disprove this inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Given a series of independent random variables $\{X_i\}$, such that: $P(X_i= i^{1/2})=\frac{1}{2i^{1/2}}$ , $P(X_i=-(i^{1/2}))=\frac{1}{2i^{1/2}}$, $P(X_i=0)=1-\frac{1}{i^{1/2}}$.i is a natural number. Prove or disprove:
limit of $P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+X_2...+X_n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right|< \frac{1}{100}\right)$ as $n\to \infty$ equals to $1$.
It seems I could use chebychev or the weak law of large numbers somehow (I already managed to see that they all have the same expectation that equals zero) ...any ideas ?

Comment: Have you already tried to evaluate $\mathbb E(X^2)$? At the first glance it goes to infinity.

Comment: I actually did, and got that it equals to the (1+2^(1/2)+3^(1/2)...n^(1/2)). But how does it help?

Comment: Is there a misprint? Do you want to divide the sum by n or by 2?

Comment: @stos1512 First of all what is your result? And secondly are you sure that this term is right?

Comment: No misprint.  This is is exactly how the problem is written..im trying to work with the weak law of the large numbers and maybe divide by n and multiply by 2...no success yet..